# Imported Namespaces in .ASPX file are appearing as plain text on browser

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, import, namespaces

I'm creating a login.aspx file for a new website I'm building, but have come up against a very odd problem. I'm trying to import some C# namespaces, but when I trial the file on a browser the <%@...%> imports appear as plain text at the top of the browser page.

I suspect this to be a simple syntax error, but from everything I've seen on forums all seems to be correct. Can anybody see what's going on here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<%@Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Security" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Security.Cryptography" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Text" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" %>

<html>

<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>Log In</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think aspnet is not installed/enabled on your server or localhost. Make sure asp.net is enabled in IIS.

Comment: ASP.Net is turned off by default in windows to reduce potential attack vectors. In the Add/Remove Programs | Add/Remove windows features open up the IIS node and enabled the ASP.net features. They are under the development node I believe.